# Hyphenation of frequency-dependently

Tags: adverbs, hyphenation

If, for example, a sound or signal is amplified depending on its frequency, would it be rather correct to write

*a frequency-dependently amplified tone*,

*a frequency-dependently-amplified tone*, or

*a frequency dependently amplified tone*?

I use the adjective frequency-dependent (with a hyphen) but somehow using the hyphen in the adverb strikes me as odd.

I am aware of the fact that none of this might be an elegant formulation, but, unfortunately, in some cases I can't avoid using it.

Comment: It's just weird.

Comment: Why use the -ly?

Comment: Because it's an adverb to the past-tense verb amplified. The amplification depends on the frequency. If I write *frequency-dependent amplified tone*, the amplified tone would depend on the frequency, which makes no sense.

Comment: Of your options, I would go with Option 2 because it ties the amplification of the tone to the frequency of the tone. That said, it not an easy phrase for your reader to understand, so I would go with something simpler and clearer, e.g., *a tone amplified based on its frequency*. Your audience would appreciate it if they knew the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, there is nothing wrong with the following:

> … a dependently <sup>(adverb)</sup> amplified <sup>(past-tense verb)</sup> tone <sup>(noun)</sup>
>
> … a dependently amplified tone

But what it lacks is a description of what the act of amplification was dependent on.

---

There is also nothing wrong with this:

> ​… a frequency <sup>(attributive noun)</sup> dependency <sup>noun</sup>
>
> … a frequency dependency

The problem comes when you want to combine those two concepts.

---

We can parse the construction of the sentence in the question:

> ✘ … a frequency-dependently <sup>(noun-modified adverb)</sup> amplified <sup>(past-tense verb)</sup> tone <sup>(noun).</sup>
>
> ✘ … a frequency-dependently amplified tone.

At the very least, this is so unidiomatic that even if some kind of defence of its syntactical integrity could be made, it wouldn't matter. It's not a construction that can be reasonably accepted.

The problem seems to come from using a noun-modified adverb.

---

We can have a noun-modified adjective that acts adverbially and which comes after a verb:

> She smiled *Gorgon-like*, freezing me in fear.

More traditionally, we can have an adverb-modified adverb before a verb:

> She *very quickly* ran down the stairs.

But neither of these are noun-modified adverbs coming before a verb, nor do they help with the sentence in the question.

Although I can't definitively prove you can't have a noun-modified adverb, it seems unlikely, and I will drop that line of investigation.

---

However, consider this:

> … a frequency-dependent tone amplification

Although [*amplification*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amplification) is a noun, it describes an action:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : an act, example, or product of amplifying

Using that as a basis, we can reconstruct the problematic phrase in a way that, while slightly awkward, is nonetheless grammatical and still preserves the sense of the original:

> ✘ … a frequency-dependently amplified tone
>
> ✔ … a tone produced from frequency-dependent amplification

This reconstructed version can be dropped into any sentence where the original, ungrammatical version had been previously attempted.

---

As suggested in a comment, a complete rephrasing of the sentence could also express the same thing:

> … a tone that was amplified based on its frequency

It's simpler, but also uses a different style.

Which essential version to choose, with or without further tweaks, is subjective.

Comment: Is this better than *a tone amplified based on its frequency*?

Comment: @RichardKayser Hmm. I *personally* think it sounds better. It certainly preserves the stylistic nature of the original phrase, and what seems like an implicit request to preserve *frequency-dependent* (at least essentially). I also think *a tone amplified based* sounds odd. I might rephrase that to *a tone **that was** amplified based on its frequency*.

Comment: I think including ***that was*** would depend on the context, but I see it as a minor difference. Either way, IMHO, what I suggested is much clearer, and if *I* were writing this, I wouldn't sacrifice clarity for style, if that's what one could call it. I wouldn't try to scratch my left ear with my right hand.